# How to help child with autism (Asperger's) through, and prevent meltdowns

Tags: middle-childhood, autism, special-needs, asperger

My ex wife and I live 2000 miles away from each other.  The children are with her.  We have been separated for over seven years, divorce will be finalized in the upcoming months.

My eldest has Asperger's syndrome, as do I.  Up until this point, I have always been able to talk her down.  Since we think very much alike, this has been easy for me to do... until now.

She is now 10, and soon to be 11 and the meltdowns have gotten worse and the fact that she has started puberty early is likely contributing.

They are starting to get severe enough to start to cause medical concerns.

- She is eating less than she should, leaving her severely underweight
- She is hyperventilating
- she will stay in this state, and being unconsolable for hours at times.

So, my question is twofold.

1. Are there any relaxation techniques or other ways to break her out of the obsessive cycle she gets in when having a meltdown.
2. Are there any relaxation, centering, coping techniques that I can teach her so she can prevent, or at least limit the onset of the attacks.

**NOTE: She cannot take pills due to a physiological problem that affects her swallowing.**

To further clarify, my ex wife lives in a very remote area, so support groups aren't really an option.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Parenting!  Have you spoken to her doctor about it? Also, what techniques have you tried now (or have you tried any yet)?  Are you the custodial parent, or are you generally trying to help from afar, or are you asking for help for your ex-wife?

Comment: @Joe their mother has custody, our daughter's currently seeing a therapist, I am helping from afar, but am looking for techniques that either I or the ex-wife can teach her.  My techniques are no longer working.

Comment: Join a specialist support group for parents of autistic kids, it has helped my friend so much.

Comment: @WendyG that's not practical due to the remoteness of location of where my daughter and her mother are living.  There simply aren't any groups because there aren't that many people.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster online is just as good, you are just more likely to get good "oh have you tried? it worked for me" answers than here

Comment: @WendyG well, it's worth a shot.  Our problem is she's so damn smart, she outmaneuvers the experts we've taken her to.  She's several grades advanced in her schoolwork

Comment: I would recommend www.mumsnet.com special needs board as a really sound bunch of women, men are allowed in certain ways as we realise men are incapable of making their own parenting boards yet the sheer volume of photography/ car boards they seem able to maintain is amazing

Comment: @WendyG are you in the UK?  They are light-years ahead of the US in understanding autism.  Thanks for the link, I'll forward it to the ex wife.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster yep i am from the UK.

Comment: @WendyG I've got the savant skill of "pattern recognition".  I can usually tell where someone is from in the world after only a few sentences, or at least figure out where they learned English.  I

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster I bet it was using the phrase "really sound" as a compliment :)

Comment: What stops you from going to the support groups, since she cannot ? You can share the information and both be better parents. (I'm an aspie myself btw)  As far as I know, its not compulsory to take a child and indeed many cannot bring their children.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster Is your ex- wife even recognising the autism of your daughter and willing to do something about it. Sorry for asking, but from your question this is quite unclear. Why is she not asking her for herself?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like my son. Still can't swallow pills. Thankfully from my own breakdowns, I have experience with the right medication. Half a lorazepam tablet quickly disolves on the toungue. Within 30 minutes there is calm from the anxiety attack. If my son has a presentation that he is having anxiety about, he will take it before that class so his nerves are in check before presenting.

As for non medication help. The more situations that you can help her through, the more she will realize that the biggest hurdle she has is her fears and anxiety.

My sister-in-law's son is autistic, not Asperger's. Her approach is when she sees him starting to go towards a meltdown in his behaviours, she quickly gets his attention and addresses the situation.

My son is learning CBT with a therapist. The information is online as well.
In my own reading, I bring to him DBT. The idea being that not everything that enters ones mind needs to be reacted to.